# How to schedule a job twice a day

Tags: scheduled-apex, cron

I have a job and I have to schedule this Job twice a day.

Currently it is running at 12 PM ET and 1 PM ET. So my Cron String looks like this.

```
public static String CRON_STR = '0 0 12,13 ? * MON-FRI *';
```

But instead of 1 hour, I want it to run at 12:01 PM ET and 12:15 PM ET.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to schedule 2 instances:

```
public static String CRON_STR = '0 1 12 ? * MON-FRI *';
public static String CRON_STR_2 = '0 15 12 ? * MON-FRI *';
```

Then:

```
System.schedule('Job 1', CRON_STR, new YourClass());
System.schedule('Job 2', CRON_STR_2, new YourClass());
```

Comment: Can't we construct a single cron string ??

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can only do that with hours and greater units. When it comes down to minutes and seconds, multiple jobs are required.

Comment: This definitely works but - I think we can achieve it in single CRON and schedule, check my answer below. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

Earlier I thought that this can be done using a single Cron expression.

```
public static String CRON_STR = '0 1,15 12 ? * MON-FRI *';
```

If you want to validate, please enter this cron at http://www.cronmaker.com/ and check the future runs.

[image]

### BUT

Apparently **CRON in Apex** do not support comma separated parameters in Minutes and Seconds. So we are stuck with 2 options :

1. Either scheduling 2 jobs like Accepted Answer, or
2. Getting creative by scheduling a following job in the Finish() method of your batch class to ensure optimum resource utilization.

Comment: But I am getting below Error:
System.StringException: Seconds and minutes must be specified as integers: 0 1,15 12 ? * MON-FRI *

Comment: I did not try scheduling, I just tried genering CRON. Let me check

Comment: Corrected my Answer!